# How can I extract the value of a given key?

Tags: python, regex

How can i extract abandonment from this string `('type=weaksubj len=1 word1=abandonment pos1=noun stemmed1=n priorpolarity=negative')`?

One possible way can be -

(This is a python Code)

```
regexp = re.findall("word1=[a-zA-Z0-9]*",string)
```

But in the result i get

```
['word1=abandonment']
```

How can i modify the regex so I don't get **'word1'** with the result.
The **'word1'** can be removed using any string function in python but i wish to modify my regex.

Comment: `re.findall("word1=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)",string)`

Comment: Or, if you don't want to use capture groups - `(?<=word1=)[a-zA-Z0-9]*`.

Comment: Potentially, you could extract it by reading the documentation for the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the key-value pairs are unique, and always have this same format, you can obtain the result you need with no regex by splitting and creating a dictionary:

```
s = 'type=weaksubj len=1 word1=abandonment pos1=noun stemmed1=n priorpolarity=negative'
dct  = dict([x.split("=") for x in s.split()])
print(dct) # => {'stemmed1': 'n', 'len': '1', 'word1': 'abandonment', 'priorpolarity': 'negative', 'type': 'weaksubj', 'pos1': 'noun'} 
print(dct['word1']) # => abandonment
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iihdFv)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the Group you want to return in brackets and then look up the group (0 in this case).

```
res= re.search("word1=([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)",mystring)
whatyourelookingfor = res.group[0]
```